# Two sequences of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

Consider two sequences of random variables $X_n, Y_n$ and suppose $X_n\to X$ in distribution. Does the following hold: $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[|X_n-Y_n|]=0 \implies Y_n\to X$ in distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by convergence in distribution? maybe you meant in probability?

Comment: @Mercy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_distribution#Convergence_in_distribution

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z_n = Y_n - X_n$. From the assumption, we have $Y_n = X_n + Z_n$, where $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $Z_n \to 0$ in $L^1$.

Then $Z_n \to 0$ in probability, and therefore by [Slutsky's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) we have the desired conclusion.